# Similarity between the text and the name of a file. need to be more imprecise

Tags: c#, file-search

I am creating a software that would allow me to sort but music by the top 100 charts automatically by fetching the top 100 on a website as well as retrieving the titles via a path database from my PC

I have already managed to retrieve the artist name and titles of the top 100 in my datagridview. (https://prnt.sc/pnndw1)

I also managed to recover most local localization of music on my PC, but not all because the sensitive case blocks me ...

I would like to know if anyone would have a solution so that it compares the value given by the website and the value that I have on my pc without taking the special characters that could disturb example : " , . | ( ) "  etc..

I would like to compare only the characters and/or if possible compare if the string contains all the words of the title.

The biggest problem that I would like to solve is that: "thank u, next" the comma of this title is not taken in the comparison

example if my file location contains: "Ramenez la coupe à la maison"
but not in the same order take it anyway.

```
wordResponse = song name.

string wordResponse = item_text.Replace("'", "’").Replace("&amp;", "&");

using (StreamReader myFile = File.OpenText(@"C:\MUSIQUE.txt"))
{
    int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
    int lineNumber = 0;

    while (!myFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = myFile.ReadLine();
        lineNumber++;
        int position = line.IndexOf(wordResponse, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (position != -1)
        {
            count++;
            (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add(line);
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Is this a long way of asking *"How can I determine if one sentence contains all the words of another sentence, ignoring specific characters"*? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: In a few words I wish that the title given by the site be searched in a file containing all the access paths of my music and that it return all the potential titles that match, but characters such as commas, brackets... I wish it was not counted in the comparison

Comment: But also the order is not important, correct? You stated, *"if my file location contains: "Ramenez la coupe à la maison" but not in the same order take it anyway."* Does that mean if the search term was *"maison la coupe"*, the title above would be returned?

Comment: Yes, if the name is only "coupe à la maison" it returned in my combobox choice all file with this text while retourned

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this question boils down to:

> "How can I determine if one sentence contains all the words of another sentence, ignoring specific characters"

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to:

1. Remove special characters from both the source string and the search string
2. Get all the "words" from each (split them on the space character)
3. See if all the words in the search string are contained in the list of words from teh source string

If that's the case, then here are some helper methods that can do this:

```
public static bool ContainsWords(string source, string search, 
    List<char> charsToIgnore = null, bool ignoreCase = true)
{
    var comparer = ignoreCase ? StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase : StringComparer.Ordinal;
    var sourceWords = GetWords(RemoveChars(source, charsToIgnore));
    var searchWords = GetWords(RemoveChars(search, charsToIgnore));

    return searchWords.All(searchWord => sourceWords.Contains(searchWord, comparer));
}

public static string RemoveChars(string input, List<char> charsToRemove)
{
    // If input or charsToIgnore are null or empty, return input
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || charsToRemove?.Any() != true) return input;

    return string.Concat(input.Where(chr => !charsToRemove.Contains(chr)));
}

public static List<string> GetWords(string input)
{
    return input?.Split(' ').ToList() ?? new List<string>();
}
```

In use this might look like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tracks = new List<string>
    {
        "Thank You, Next.",
        "Sweet But Psycho (One of Six Hardstyle Remix)",
    };

    // Note that this prevents someone from searching
    // for all titles that have a comma in the name
    var charsToIgnore = new List<char>
    {
        ',', '.', '!', ';', ':', '(', ')'
    };

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a parital title to search for: ");
        var search = Console.ReadLine();

        var matches = tracks.Where(track => ContainsWords(track, search, charsToIgnore));

        Console.WriteLine($"Matches found: {0}",
            matches.Any() ? string.Join(", ", matches) : "[None]");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Note that this will prevent users from searching for all titles that contain one of the characters in our "ignore" list, like a comma or a parenthesis:

[image]

Comment: Okay, i while test this in few times !
Thanks !

My file name is composed of path (E:\xxxx\xxxx\filename.mp3) but but I don't think have any problems with that...

Comment: If you are searching full path strings like `"E:\xxxx\xxxx\filename.mp3"`, but you really only want to compare the string `"filename"` (the name of the file, without the extension or path), then you can use: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("E:\xxxx\xxxx\filename.mp3")`

Comment: Okay, a big thank you to you!
I adapted to my software its work perfectly, I'm a beginner yet I don't use too many pointers but I got away with it aha.
60 seconds to find the titles online and find their local path! I think it can be improved for sure!
But always faster than picking up each music with your hands: -P